# Having issues getting an alias or bash function to force chef-client to alway log

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I'm trying to get it to on ever run automatically log to a time stamped log file so we can track changes

I've tried

```
alias chef-client='chef-client -L $LOGFILE '
```

and if I do chef-client -W, I get invalid option -W

I've also tried

```
alias chef-client='{ TIMESTAMP=`(date +"%F  %T")`;sudo mkdir -p /var/log/chef;LOGFILE="chef-client-run-$TIMESTAMP";echo "LogName $LOGFILE";chef-client -L $LOGFILE "$@"; }'
```

and

```
function chef-client() {
      TIMESTAMP=(date +"%F %T")
       FILENAME="/var/log/chef/chef-client-run-$TIMESTAMP"
       chef-client "-L $FILENAME $@";
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like a problem with the way you're quoting things. If I understand your intended result correctly, I think the last line of your function should be `chef-client -L "$FILENAME" "$@"`.

Comment: Please verify that `chef-client -L $LOGFILE -W` works before trying to alias to it. Make especially sure to actually copy-paste it into a shell to run it exactly as posted. Avoid the pitfalls of saying that it works based on belief that it should, or based on the observation that a different command you believe is identical works (such as `chef-client -L myfile -W`)

Comment: You should absolutely be using a function instead of an alias in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this in the config file (`/etc/chef/client.rb`):

```
require "time"
log_location "/var/log/chef/chef-client-run/#{Time.now.iso8601}.log"
```

Or something like that, adjust the formatting of the timestamp as desired.

Also, if you want to track changes, I wouldn't use the log output. Make an event handler and track the actual data you want.

Comment: It should still log to STDOUT automatically if it's an interactive run and the formatter system isn't active, I think at least. You can always force it by manually configuring an extra logger, Basically `Chef::Log.loggers` is an array and you can put in any object that matches Ruby's logging API.